# How to fix issue with svg element not rendering into image (dom2img)

Tags: javascript, svg, amcharts, html2canvas, amcharts4

I'm using amcharts4 to build heat map and then via [dom2img](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image) I'm transforming that into image. Everything is fine and map itself is rendered but legend is not captured with dom2img. Legend itself is an svg element.

I thought maybe it has something to do with gradient because that's the only element with it.

svg element:

```
<g fill-opacity="1" fill="url(&quot;http://localhost:4200/campaigns/pptx/2#gradient-id-257&quot;)" style="pointer-events: none;"><path d="M0,0 L455,0 a0,0 0 0 1 0,0 L455,20 a0,0 0 0 1 -0,0 L0,20 a0,0 0 0 1 -0,-0 L0,0 a0,0 0 0 1 0,-0 Z"></path></g>
```

Dom2img should render legend element.

Comment: did you tried output in different browsers?

Comment: Please try moving the gradient (and anything else you may have) from localhost in the `<defs>` of your svg

Comment: @MangeshSathe I've tried Firefox and Chrome. Same result

Comment: @enxaneta I don't really know how would I do this. I'm using library that builds everything itself.

Answer (score 1):

Use amCharts built-in export feature instead: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/exporting/

```
// First enable export
chart.exporting.menu = new am4core.ExportMenu();

chart.exporting.extraSprites.push({
    "sprite": legendContainer,
    "position": "bottom",
    "marginTop": 20
});

// Then you can get the Base64 image
var imgData = chart.exporting.getImage("png");
```

You can also include the legend using `extraSprites` as shown above. Read more about [including external legend in export](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/chart-legend-in-an-external-container/#Including_external_legend_in_export).

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this one but unfortunately it had the same result. Legend is not render (no colors and just numbers)